# Создание относительного пути к иконке ярлыка

Tags: windows, shortcuts

У меня есть ярлык к файлу. Путь ярлыка "\папка\ярлык". Этот ярлык имеет определённую несистемную иконку в папке. Путь иконки "\папка\подпапка\иконка". Вопрос: как задать относительный путь к иконке, чтобы при перемещении "папка" в другое место иконка ярлыка сохранялась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, `Windows` не поддерживает относительные пути к иконкам в ярлыках. Даже если Вы [создадите новую переменную среды окружения](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm) и присвоите ей путь к Вашей папке, а саму переменную используете в качестве источника иконки, то после перемещения Вашей папки, относительный путь станет "недействительным" и иконка пропадет. Тем не менее, до выхода из системы иконка остается той, которая была указана *до* выполнения различных манипуляций с папкой,содержащей иконку.

На рисунке ниже показана добавленная переменная среды окружения под названием `SHRTCT`, имеющая значение `C:\ShortCut`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее указываем нашу новую переменную среды окружения в качестве *относительного* пути к иконке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после перемещения\удаления\что-либо еще нашей папки `ShortCut`, попытка смены значка окончится провалом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Таким образом, относительный путь для иконки ярлыка штатными средствами `Windows` установить невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, это невозможно сделать с помощью стандартных средств Windows. Я использовал программу Advanced Installer, которая при создании установщика позволяет указать относительный путь к изображению ярлыка (если оно находится в папке, которая будет устанавливаться созданным .exe файлом). Когда пользователь установит вашу программу, ярлык будет с нужной иконкой (если в итоге пользователь не станет перемещать файлы программы).